# Can I mute/unmute an UIWebview in some way?

Tags: ios, audio, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView which generates sound, but I want to remove it. How can I mute the audio output in a `UIWebView`?

Answer (score 3):

I've found the way to mute/unmute single player UIWebView. Any time UIWebView starts video AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification notification fired. So handle it and track current AVPlayerItem to control playback.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    …

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemBecameCurrent:)
                                                 name:@"AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"
                                               object:nil];
}

-(void)playerItemBecameCurrent:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    if ([notification.object isKindOfClass:[AVPlayerItem class]]) {
        self.currentItem = (AVPlayerItem*)notification.object;
    }
}

-(void)muteSound:(BOOL)mute
{   
    AVAsset *asset = self.currentItem.asset;
    NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

    NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks)
    {
        AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];

        [audioInputParams setVolume:!mute atTime:kCMTimeZero];

        [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
        [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
    }

    AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    [audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

    self.currentItem.audioMix = audioZeroMix;

}
```

Comment: but not this notification fired in WKWebView how to get avplyer from it please help me .

Answer (score 0):

This will be the easiest way.

```
-(void)stopAudio
{
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"" ]]];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't want to remove the content of the UIWebview.

Comment: self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;

Comment: You can also add a AVAudioPlayer framework and set the Volume to 0. http://mobileorchard.com/easy-audio-playback-with-avaudioplayer/ (Tutorial)

Comment: Your second suggestion doesn't work, the AVAudioPlayer is used when you want to load an audio, but you cannot use in a UIWebview directly.

Comment: Your last answer looks really nice, but it is muting the whole app.